# elegant python pattern search without if-else statement

Tags: python, regex

Is there an elegant one-line way to find a number that contains 7 except if it is just 7?

```
if  re.search(r'(\d+)?(7)(\d+)', line):
    print "Found 7 inside or beginning of a number", match.group()
else:
    if  re.search(r'(\d+)(7)(\d+)?', line):
        print "Found 7 in the end of a number", match.group()
```

Comment: `(\d+)?` is an awkward way to write `\d*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean

```
'7' in line and len(line) > 1
```

You can also use [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check if all the characters are digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution involving regex, since you asked that specifically:

```
re.search("(7.)|(.7)", line)
```